# Need help on Java Rainfall program

Tags: java

So I have to make the Java rainfall program. The thing is my professor wants me to submit it using myprogramminglab which is extremely sensitive if you don't get exactly the same output of mpl it gets marked wrong all the down to the spacing.   I've got most of the program done only thing really i'm having trouble with is outputting the largest month and smallest month as a String and the input validation.

Here's the assignment:

> Write a RainFall class  that has the following field:
>
> • an array  of doubles  that stores  the rainfall for each of the 12
>   months of the year (where the first index corresponds with January,
>   the second with February, etc.)
>
> The class  should also have the following methods :
>
> • a method  that returns the total rainfall for the entire year
>   • a method  that returns the average monthly rainfall for the year
>   • a method  that returns the month with the most rain as a string
>   • a method  that returns the month with the least rain as a string
>
> Demonstrate the class  in a program  that takes 12 doubles  from the
>   user (take the  doubles  in the order of the months of the year, the
>   first corresponding to the  rainfall in January, etc.). Do input
>   validation: if the user inputs a negative number, ignore it and
>   continue asking them for input until  you have 12 nonnegative doubles
>   .
>
> Once the user has given  you all 12 doubles , create an instance of
>   the RainFall class  and call its methods , printing out the total
>   rainfall, the average monthly rainfall, the month with the most rain,
>   and the month with the least rain, each on a separate line.

Here's the output mpl wants the floating periods represent spaces and the arrows

```
newlines:
Enter·rainfall·for·month·1:1.12↵
Enter·rainfall·for·month·2:2.24↵
Enter·rainfall·for·month·3:3.36↵
Enter·rainfall·for·month·4:0.48↵
Enter·rainfall·for·month·5:2.00↵
Enter·rainfall·for·month·6:5.00↵
Enter·rainfall·for·month·7:12.12↵
Enter·rainfall·for·month·8:1.48↵
Enter·rainfall·for·month·9:3.12↵
Enter·rainfall·for·month·10:3.24↵
Enter·rainfall·for·month·11:6.6↵
Enter·rainfall·for·month·12:1.12↵
41.88↵
3.49↵
July↵
April↵
```

And here's my code

```
public class rainFall 
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String rain[] = {"January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "November", "December"};

        static double sum = 0;
        static double avg = 0;
        int m = 1;
        double numbers = 0;

        public void setSum()
        {
           while(m < 13)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter rainfall for month " + m + ":");
                numbers = input.nextDouble();
                sum+= numbers;
                m++;
            } 
        }

        public double getSum()
        {
            return sum;
        }

        public void setAverage()
        {
            avg = sum / 12;
        }

        public double getAverage()
        {
            return avg;
        }

        public String getLargest()
        {
            String largest = rain[0];
            int r = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < numbers; i++)
            {
                if(rain[i] > numbers)
                {
                    r = i;
                }
            }

            return r;
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        rainFall rf = new rainFall();
        rf.setSum();
        rf.setAverage();

        System.out.println(rf.getSum());
        System.out.println(rf.getAverage());
    }
}
```

My only errors are  bad operands types at the if statement and the return statement in getLargest()

Comment: Your if condition makes no logical sense -- how can a String, `rain[i]` be greater than `numbers`, a double?? What are you trying to do there? What exactly are you thinking that you're testing?

Comment: You're not even following the instructions -- where's your array of doubles?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble with is outputting the largest month and smallest month as a String

That'll be really hard to get considering you don't store the rainfall for any single month. You just have the sum.

> ```
>     public void setSum()
>     {
>        while(m < 13)
>         {
>             System.out.print("Enter rainfall for month " + m + ":");
>             numbers = input.nextDouble();
>             sum+= numbers;
>             m++;
>         } 
>     }
> ```

And also, this loop in here doesn't work how you think it does. Try naming your variables better, you'll see this problem

> ```
> double numbers = 0; // This is a singular value, not plural. 
>
> for(int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) // This will loop, but not 'every month'
> {
>     if(rain[i] > numbers) // Here you compare a `String > double` ... not going to work
>     {
>         r = i;
>     }
> }
> ```

And you want to return the month's **name**, not the index of that `rain` array.

---

Here's an example of getting month amounts with a  `HashMap<String, Double>`

```
    HashMap<String, Double> amounts = new HashMap<String, Double>();

    public void setSum()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rain.length; i++) {
            String month = rain[i];
            if (!amounts.containsKey(month) {
                amounts.put(month, 0);
            }

            System.out.print("Enter rainfall for month " + month + ":");
            double input = input.nextDouble();
            amounts.put(month, amounts.get(month) + input);


            sum += numbers;
        } 
    }
```

Then research how to loop over a HashMap and find the smallest / greatest value for every key.

**However**, your instructions say this

> an array of doubles that stores the rainfall for each of the 12 months of the year

So, you will need an `double[]`